# I don't know how to submit a multiple tag inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, forms

I found a YouTube tutorial that showed me how to create a multiple tag input field but I couldn't figure out how to save the inputs (as JSON) to my Django models.
I am new to JavaScript, so I don't know what to do here.

My goal is to submit the tag inputs along with other inputs in my HTML form

### JavaScript

```
const ul = document.querySelector("ul[name=features-ul]"),
input = document.querySelector("input[name=features]"),
tagNumb = document.querySelector(".tag-details span");

let maxTags = 16,
tags = ["coding"];
var features = {"input[name=features]" : tags}

countTags();
createTag();

function countTags(){
    input.focus();
    tagNumb.innerText = maxTags - tags.length;
}

function createTag(){
    ul.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li => li.remove());
    tags.slice().reverse().forEach(tag =>{
        let liTag = `<li>${tag} <i class="uit uit-multiply" onclick="remove(this, '${tag}')"></i></li>`;
        ul.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", liTag);
    });
    countTags();
}

function remove(element, tag){
    let index  = tags.indexOf(tag);
    tags = [...tags.slice(0, index), ...tags.slice(index + 1)];
    element.parentElement.remove();
    countTags();
}

function addTag(e){
    if(e.key == "Enter"){
        let tag = e.target.value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        if(tag.length > 1 && !tags.includes(tag)){
            if(tags.length < 16){
                tag.split(',').forEach(tag => {
                    tags.push(tag);
                    createTag();
                });
            }
        }
        e.target.value = "";
    }
}

input.addEventListener("keyup", addTag);

const removeBtn = document.querySelector(".tag-details button");
removeBtn.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    tags.length = 0;
    ul.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li => li.remove());
    countTags();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).keydown(function(event){
      if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
```

### html

Property Features:

```
                                        <div class="tag-wrapper">
                                        <div class="tag-content">
                                          <p>Press enter or add a comma after each tag</p>
                                          <ul name="features-ul"><input type="text" id="features" spellcheck="false" name="features">
                                        </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tag-details">
                                          <p><span>16</span> tags are remaining</p>
                                          <button>Clear All Tags</button>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>

                                    </div>
```

Comment: `<ul>something</ul>` is invalid markup. must have `<li>` children. As for your question, there are 2 options. Either you have a hidden input and you update it as soon as a tag is added or removed. Or you catch the `submit` event and then build the json string out of the `<li>`s.

Comment: @ITgoldman can you help me with a demo code for the hidden input

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a button for submitting the tags to your HTML.

e.g.

```
<div class="tags-submit">
    <button>Submit tags</button>
</div>
```

Then you need add a function for submitting the tags and an event listener for the button.

e.g.

```js
function submitTags() {
  fetch("http://url-here/to/send/tags", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
    body: JSON.stringify({tags: tags})
  }).then(res => {
    console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
  });
}


const submitBtn = document.querySelector(".tags-submit button");
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    submitTags();
});
```

Comment: it's still not getting passed.... i check the form data on developer tools and the value is empty

Comment: There is no form data in this script the tags are stored in the variable `tags`. Check the network tab in developer tools and look for the POST call.

Comment: yeah that is what i checked, i had no data there

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle with the code https://jsfiddle.net/gncL0jwo/ this does send the data if you check the payload tab.

Comment: i think the issue is Django not getting the values......... should i post the whole form??

Comment: You may post the whole form, but do you see the payload in the developers tab now?

Comment: i see the payload but it's only for my form

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTG147/heqtg87v/2/ this is it

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to handle key 13 properly. Check out the relevant code. Also, my bad, the `tags` variable already contains the required JSON. So this should work to get the JSON. Also the answer of `@Ervin van hoof` correctly sends it as AJAX to the server.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector("ul[name=features-ul]"),
  input = document.querySelector("input[name=features]"),
  tagNumb = document.querySelector(".tag-details span"),
  btn2 = document.querySelector(".btn2")

let maxTags = 16,
  tags = ["coding"];
var features = {
  "input[name=features]": tags
}

countTags();
createTag();

function countTags() {
  input.focus();
  tagNumb.innerText = maxTags - tags.length;
}

function createTag() {
  ul.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li => li.remove());
  tags.slice().reverse().forEach(tag => {
    let liTag = `<li>${tag} <i class="uit uit-multiply" onclick="remove(this, '${tag}')"></i></li>`;
    ul.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", liTag);
  });
  countTags();
}

function remove(element, tag) {
  let index = tags.indexOf(tag);
  tags = [...tags.slice(0, index), ...tags.slice(index + 1)];
  element.parentElement.remove();
  countTags();
}

function addTag(e) {
  if (e.key == "Enter") {
    let tag = e.target.value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    if (tag.length > 1 && !tags.includes(tag)) {
      if (tags.length < 16) {
        tag.split(',').forEach(tag => {
          tags.push(tag);
          createTag();
        });
      }
    }
    e.target.value = "";
  }
}

input.addEventListener("keyup", addTag);

const removeBtn = document.querySelector(".tag-details button");
removeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  tags.length = 0;
  ul.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li => li.remove());
  countTags();
});

btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(tags)
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(input).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tag-wrapper">
  <div class="tag-content">
    <p>Press enter or add a comma after each tag</p>
    <ul name="features-ul"><input type="text" id="features" spellcheck="false" name="features">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tag-details">
    <p><span>16</span> tags are remaining</p>
    <button>Clear All Tags</button>
    <button class="btn2">
    show JSON
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```